# ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6 cannot be cast to OraclePreparedStatement

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jboss7.x, classcastexception

I'm working to migrate an application from Oracle Application Server to JBoss EAP 6.1. I have most things working but I am getting one error that I haven't been able to figure out:

```
13:27:29,743 ERROR [com.myproj.db.dao.myDao] (Thread-164) Get Prepared Statement: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6 cannot be cast
to oracle.jdbc.internal.OraclePreparedStatement
```

I have Oracle set up as a module in JBoss for connection pooling using `ojdbc6.jar` (and it works for other parts of the application), but for the one part of the application that uses an `OraclePreparedStatement`, it gets the error.

I did make certain that there is no `ojdbc6.jar` file in the WAR file.  The only one in JBoss seems to be inside of the module.

I did try changing the `OraclePreparedStatement` class to `oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement`, but the results are the same.

I did try running with TRACE on for logging to see where classes were loading from. `OraclePreparedStatement` was loaded from the module with the exception of this line:

```
4:31:40,583 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (Thread-84) Finding class 
oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement from Module "deployment.myProj.war:main" from
Service Module Loader
```

Here's a link to an [excerpt of the log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60041598/trace%20classloader%20info.txt) - basically just the lines related to `OraclePreparedStatement`.

I have confirmed that there is no `ojdbc6.jar` (or any Oracle related jars) in the WAR file, and there is no `OraclePreparedStatement` class inside of the WAR file either.

I do have the module listed as a dependency in my JBoss deployment structure xml file.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I assume you are using Oracle specific extensions that mean you need to cast to OraclePreparedStatement?

Comment: @Mark, Yes. The code is casting a `PreparedStatement` to an `OraclePreparedStatement` so that it can . As I am simply trying to move an old project (that I didn't write) from Oracle Application Server to JBoss, I don't really want to have to rewrite the class file.

Comment: From a quick look at the javadoc try first casting to `org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6` then call `getUnderlyingStatement` and try to cast that object to `oracle.jdbc.internal.OraclePreparedStatement`.

Comment: @Mark - that seemed to work.    `    if (a instanceof WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6)
   {
    WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6 b = (WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6) a;
    stmt = (OraclePreparedStatement) b.getUnderlyingStatement();
   } else
   {
    stmt = (OraclePreparedStatement) a;
   }`  If you want to write of an official answer, I will mark it as accepted for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the javadoc I would guess that `org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6` is wrapping the underlying Oracle JDBC driver.

`org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6` has a method to get the underlying statement. Perhaps you should try something like the following:

```
WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6 statement = ...
OraclePreparedStatement oracleStatement = (OraclePreparedStatement)statement.getUnderlyingStatement();
```