# weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Array_oracle_sql_ARRAY cannot be cast to oracle.sql.ARRAY

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, weblogic12c, classcastexception

I am an facing error in weblogic:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Array_oracle_sql_ARRAY cannot be cast to oracle.sql.ARRAY at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.CallableStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleCallableStatementWrapper.getARRAY(Unknown Source)

Code:

```
   public String[] methodName(String[] P1,String P2,String P3,String P4, String P5,int Sessioninfo)
{
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement cstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String[] returnArray = null;

    try {
        ds=getDataSource(Sessioninfo);
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        conn = new CommonsDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor().getNativeConnection(conn);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        ArrayDescriptor oracleVarchar2Collection =
                ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("VARRAY_PARTS",conn);
        ARRAY sqlNos = new ARRAY(oracleVarchar2Collection, conn, P1);

        cstmt =conn.prepareCall("{call Procedure1(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
        cstmt.setObject(1, sqlNos);
        cstmt.setString(2, P2);
        cstmt.setString(3, WebpartsUtility.convertSQLStringIN(P3,","));
        cstmt.setString(4, WebpartsUtility.convertSQLStringIN(P4,","));
        cstmt.setString(5,P5);

        cstmt.registerOutParameter(6,OracleTypes.ARRAY, "VARRAY_PARTS");

        cstmt.setFetchSize(2500);
        cstmt.execute();
        ARRAY mainArray = ((OracleCallableStatement)cstmt).getARRAY(6);
        returnArray = (String[]) mainArray.getArray();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        logger.fatalMsg("Sql Exception Occured :: "+ex.getMessage(),ex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.fatalMsg("Exception Occured :: "+ex.getMessage(),ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (cstmt != null) {
                cstmt.close();
                cstmt = null;
            }                       
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
                conn = null;
            }
            if (ds != null) {
                ds = null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            logger.fatalMsg("Sql Exception Occured :: "+ex.getMessage(),ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.fatalMsg("Exception Occured :: "+ex.getMessage(),ex);
        }
    }

    return returnArray;
}
```

Comment: It's good to post error messages and code, if you have any idea as to what it could be, it's good to post that too.

Answer (score 3):

A simple parameter change in the datasource should make it work.

Go to datasource -> select the datasource -> Configuration -> Connection Pool -> Advanced then uncheck "Wrap Data Types".

This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the connection is returned as a wrapper around the native connection and you need to unwrap it:

```
conn = new CommonsDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor().getNativeConnection(conn);
OracleConnection oConn;
if ( conn.isWrapperFor( OracleConnection.class ) )
{
  oConn = (OracleConnection) conn.unwrap( OracleConnection.class );
}
else
{
  oConn = (OracleConnection) conn;
}
```

Or, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21125974/1509264),  you could get the underlying callable statement (and not a wrapped statement):

```
OracleCallableStatement cstmt
    = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{call Procedure1(?,?,?,?,?,?)}")
                                    .getUnderlyingStatement();
```

Another potential solution would be to not use intermediate variables and just do:

```
returnArray = (String[]) ((OracleCallableStatement)cstmt).getARRAY(6).getArray();
```

**Update**:

Based on [this answer](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2339937?start=0) you could also try:

```
ARRAY mainArray = (ARRAY) ((weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Array) (callableStmt).getObject(3))
                              .unwrap(ARRAY.class);
```

Comment: None of these worked in my case. Still facing the same error: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Array_oracle_sql_ARRAY cannot be cast to oracle.sql.ARRAY

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved adding the below code:

```
           try {
        statement.setLong(1, new Long(1));
        statement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY, "TNUMBERTABLE");
        statement.execute();
        ARRAY ar = null;
        Object someArray = statement.getArray(2);
        if (someArray instanceof weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Array)
            ar =
      (oracle.sql.ARRAY(((weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Array)someArray).unwrap(Class.forName("oracle.sql.ARRAY")));
        else
            ar = (oracle.sql.ARRAY)someArray;

        for (long i : ar.getLongArray()) {
            //code if needed
        }

    }
```

You can check this link:http://adfpractice-fedor.blogspot.com/2011/09/weblogic-wrapping-data-types.html